# How to remove default text written below body tag in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing a problem . As you can see "http://hair-on-demand.com/" a text "page-content" is written in the left-top . I checked header.php but there is nothing written . Anyone knows from where this text is generating ?

Comment: You appear to have a nested `html` document within your page source. Are you using some sort of web page generator?

Comment: I am using themeforest.net/item/beauty-center-responsive-wordpress-theme  this theme and It doesnt have any web page generator .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an seo plugin or something along that line b/c the following html is getting injected into `<head></head>`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="96AFF80E69D87368573FAEDC4FB70ED1" />
        <title>Your SEO optimized title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        page contents
    </body>
</html>
```

If you are I would disable that plugin or setting in the theme.

Comment: Thanks for your help , as that was not a seo plugin but it was another plugin which was creating problem.

Comment: Which plugin was causing the issue for you?

Comment: @JagjeetKumar I am experiencing the same problem, which plugin was it?